# LuaLaTeX + unicode-math + semantic package

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I am trying to use `lualatex` with the `unicode-math` and `semantic` packages. I have some problems with the `semantic` package - when I load full version or with the `shorthand` option I get "Invalid math code" errors.

The following code works correctly:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\usepackage[inference]{semantic}

\begin{document}
$$
\inference{a = b}{c}{d}
$$
\end{document}
```

And this one causes errors:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\usepackage[inference,shorthand]{semantic}

\begin{document}
$$
\inference{a = b}{c}{d}
$$
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to make it work? Or maybe there is a way to create semantic bracket symbols to use with unicode-math? (like \ldbrack \rdbrack in `mathabx` package).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use backticks, like this "`", to highlight TeX syntax items in your text. I've added some of them.

Answer (score 3):

The following hack seems to solve the problem: load the `semantic` package but embedding the call in some magic code

```
\let\ORImathcode\mathcode
\let\mathcode\Umathcodenum

\usepackage[inference,shorthand]{semantic}

\let\mathcode\ORImathcode

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\mathligsoff}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\makeatother
```

In short we tell `ligature.sty` (that is loaded by `semantic`) to use `\Umathcodenum` where it uses `\mathcode`.

If `xpatch` is not available, the lines from `\usepackage{xpatch}` can be changed into

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname mathligsoff \endcsname{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\Umathcodenum}{}{}
\makeatother
```

### EDIT

A version that can work with all three engines

```
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifunicodeengine
\ifxetex
  \unicodeenginetrue
  \let\SEMmathcodenum\XeTeXmathcodenum
\else
  \ifluatex
    \unicodeenginetrue
    \let\SEMmathcodenum\Umathcodenum
  \fi
\fi
\ifunicodeengine
  \let\ORImathcode\mathcode
  \let\mathcode\SEMmathcodenum
\fi

\usepackage[inference,shorthand]{semantic}

\ifunicodeengine
  \let\mathcode\ORImathcode

  \usepackage{xpatch}
  \makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd{\mathligsoff}{\mathcode}{\SEMmathcodenum}{}{}
  \xpatchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\SEMmathcodenum}{}{}
  \xpatchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\SEMmathcodenum}{}{}
  \xpatchcmd{\@addligto}{\mathcode}{\SEMmathcodenum}{}{}
  \makeatother
\fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I managed to bypass this in a little different fashion. I wanted to use `\eval` so I don't use `shorthand`, just redefine interesting part (turns out there is an `\rBrack` symbol ):

```
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\newcommand{\evalsymbol}[1][]{\ensuremath{\mathcal{E}^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\eval}[3][]%
  {\mbox{${\evalsymbol}^{#1}\lBrack${#2}$\rBrack$}\,{#3}}
```